# Get iframe content by http request java

Tags: java, http, iframe, request, httprequest

guys!

I'm trying to get the content of an iframe using a java HTTP request.
My code works fine, but it doesn't brings to me the iframe content, just the main code of HTML page.

The page contains an iframe id "iframeContent", but the response doesn't brings the iframe content, just his declaration on page.

I'm using this:

```
        URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

I've tried with POST method too, but doesn't work anyway.
Is there any way to get that content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to request the URL of the iframe, not of the original page. If you don't know the URL of the iframe or if it can change dynamically, you need to parse the HTML of the original page and extract the iframe URL.

Comment: I know the iframe's name, but how can I pass the URL with iframe in it? 

After, I want to take a jCaptcha image, inside the iframe, and show it on my application.

PS: I can't access the iframe directly, I need to pass by the main page.